# Прием и раздача интернета

Tags: сеть

В компьютере 2 сетевые карты. На одно из них идет кабель с интернетом, другая должна раздавать этот интернет на WiFi маршрутизатор. Собственно вопрос: как заставить сетевую карту раздавать интернет по кабелю?

Answer (score 1):

Qos вам в помощь! Почти все модемы имеют такую функцию.

Согласно вашей задаче вам необходимо раздать инет на ПК и тв(iptv)Из ваших слов "... слишком большая нагрузка и он довольно часто просто зависает." QOS может помочь настроить приоритет таким образом что бы можно было бы сидеть в нете и смотреть телевизор спокойно без напряга! Если уж так не терпится то вставляете в ван порт кабель от компа а на компе расшиваривате инет (при желании можете стелать мост между сетевухами). В настройка токи доступа прописываете статику с адресацией dns и шлюза вашего ПК. PS Вам виднее конечно но зачем прорубать дверь если она прорублена уже давно до вас!?

Comment: При чем тут QOS? Мне нужно с КОМПЬЮТЕРА раздать интернет на МАРШРУТИЗАТОР.

Comment: QOS не спасает, а только усугубляет положение, так как на устройстве начинает работать еще +1 служба. Когда маршрутизатор зависает уже ничего не сделаешь - только перезагрузка. Ваш вариант не поможет - компьютер почему то не хочет давать маршрутизатору IPTV

Comment: Уважаемый не вижу смысла в полемики. Раз уж он зависает от "+1" службы тогда обновите прошивку на сайте производителя или замените на более приличный. Сам РТК настраивает политику своих роутеров в qos для просмотра iptv. Добавить больше нечего...

Comment: @Sem ICT, как много вы видели Wi-Fi роутеров настольно-домашнего типа, которые нормально выживают с QoS при больших потоках данных (аля торрент + IPTV)?

Comment: @Dex Таковых не много но всеже присутвуют на нашем рынке. Есть хороший ряд роутеров от asus серия rt-n10 или Netgear Ну или на карайний случай TP-link  но у екго замудренная настройка Qos. Совсем недавно Ростелеком начал выдавать своим клиентам в подарок роутер-точка доступа "Sagem Fast 2804". Поверьте на нем тоже не плохо настраивается IPTV и QOS!

Comment: Ну не знаю... у мну Зухель Кинетик Лайт беспроблемно дает iptv и инет без всякого qos на два компа, причем один из них на wi-fi...или два на wi-fi. iptv естественно настроен на отдельный порт.

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю у вас ОС Windows, укажите это в своём сообщении. И укажите цель с которой вы желаете так извратиться с маршрутизацией. Разве не проще подключить интернет напрямую к wi-fi маршрутизатору и от него, хоть бы и через кабель передавать интернет на нужные ПК? На сколько мне известно, если в wi-fi маршрутизаторах есть порт для ethernet, то он как минимум не один.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня провайдер раздает мне помимо интернета и IPTV. маршрутизатор на данный момент принимает по WAN интернет и IPTV и раздает это на ноутбук (иногда) и на телевизор с компьютером - слишком большая нагрузка и он довольно часто просто зависает. Я хочу кинуть на прямую интернет к компьютеру а с компьютера уже раздавать его на маршрутизатор, что бы тот в свою очередь отдавал его телевизору и ноутбуку.

Comment: у меня дома стоит wi-fi маршрутизатор он подключен к интернету на порту №1 и раздаёт IPTV с порта №4 остальные порты работают на обмен данными (интернета) в сети, так-же интернет раздаётся и через wi-fi. проблемы не наблюдаю. Разве что вот пытаюсь IPTV через wi-fi запустить , но пока не получается.